# How to make react.js play nice together with zurb reveal modal form

Tags: zurb-foundation, reactjs, zurb-reveal

I am trying to integrate zurb reveal with form into react component. So far next code properly displays modal form:

```
ModalForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(attrs) {
    this.props.onSubmit(attrs);
    return false;
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
        <a href="#" data-reveal-id="formModal" className="button">Add new</a>
        <div id="formModal" className="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
          <h4>Add something new</h4>
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
          <a className="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The `Form` component is pretty standard:

```
Form = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function() {
    var body = this.refs.body.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    if (!body) {
      return false;
    }
    this.props.onSubmit({body: body});
    this.refs.body.getDOMNode().value = '';
    return false;
  },
  render: function(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <textarea name="body" placeholder="Say something..." ref="body" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" className="button" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

**Problem:** When I render form component within modal form component and enter something into form input then I see in console exception `Uncaught object`. This is a stack:

```
Uncaught object
  invariant
  ReactMount.findComponentRoot
  ReactMount.findReactNodeByID
  getNode
  ...
```

If I just render form component directly in the parent component then everything works. Could anybody help please?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - my guess is that Foundation's modals are manipulating the DOM and React isn't able to keep track.

Comment: @dbau, you are correct.

Comment: I made a plunk to showcase the bug - http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6y5dI?p=preview. I have also asked in a few places: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1703 and 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/qaG_qRMo29o

Comment: have a look here: https://gist.github.com/dyatlov/aa357617cf0afeb5b19f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, you're doing this wrong and this is **not** a bug in react.

If you use any kind of plugin that modifies the react component's dom nodes then it's going to break things in one way or another.

What you should be doing instead is using react itself, and complementary css, to position the component in the way you'd like for your modal dialog.

I would suggest creating a component that uses react's `statics` component property to define a couple of functions wrapping `renderComponent` to give you a nice clean function call to show or hide a react dialog.  Here's a cut down example of something I've used in the past.  NB: It does use jQuery but you could replace the jQ with standard js api calls to things like `elementById` and etc if you don't want the jQuery code.

```
window.MyDialog = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        title:      React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        content:    React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },
    statics: {

        // open a dialog with props object as props
        open: function(props) {
            var $anchor = $('#dialog-anchor');
            if (!$anchor.length) {
                $anchor = $('<div></div>')
                    .prop('id', 'dialog-anchor');
                    .appendTo('body');
            }
            return React.renderComponent(
                MyDialog(props),
                $anchor.get(0)
            );
        },

        // close a dialog
        close: function() {
            React.unmountComponentAtNode($('#dialog-anchor').get(0));
        }
    },

    // when dialog opens, add a keyup event handler to body
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $('body').on('keyup.myDialog', this.globalKeyupHandler);
    },

    // when dialog closes, clean up the bound keyup event handler on body 
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        $('body').off('keyup.myDialog');
    },

    // handles keyup events on body
    globalKeyupHandler: function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { // ESC key

            // close the dialog
            this.statics.close();
        }
    },

    // Extremely basic dialog dom layout - use your own
    render: function() {
        <div className="dialog">
            <div className="title-bar">
                <div className="title">{this.props.title}</div>
                    <a href="#" className="close" onClick={this.closeHandler}>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                {this.props.content}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
});
```

You then open a dialog by calling:

`MyDialog.open({title: 'Dialog Title', content: 'My dialog content'});`

And close it with

`MyDialog.close()`

The dialog always attaches to a new dom node directly under body with id 'dialog-anchor'.  If you open a dialog when one is already open, it will simply update the dom based on new props (or not if they're the same).

Of course passing the content of the dialog as a props argument isn't particularly useful.  I usually extend below to either parse markdown -> html for the content or get some html via an ajax request inside the component when supplying a url as a prop instead.

I know the above code isn't exactly what you were looking for but I don't think there's a good way to make a dom-modifying plugin work with react.  You can never assume that the dom representation of the react component is static and therefore it can't be manipulated by a 3rd party plugin successfully.  I honestly think if you want to use react in this way you should re-evaluate why you're using the framework.

That said, I think the code above is a great starting point for a dialog in which all manipulation occurs inside the component, which afterall is what reactjs is all about!

NB: code was written very quickly from memory and not actually tested in it's current form so sorry if there are some minor syntax errors or something.

Comment: Although I understand that what you are saying is correct, it doesn't really answer the question. The purpose of Foundation is so that you don't have to roll your own components for boilerplate stuff like this. Would be interesting to see if there was a way to get this working, even if it is not "the right way". Just my two cents.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do what Mike did, but using a zf reveal modal:

```
var Dialog = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    open: function(){
      this.$dialog = $('#my-dialog');

      if (!this.$dialog.length) {
        this.$dialog = $('<div id="my-dialog" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal role="dialog"></div>')
          .appendTo('body');
      }

      this.$dialog.foundation('reveal', 'open');

      return React.render(
        <Dialog close={this.close.bind(this)}/>,
        this.$dialog[0]
      );
    },
    close: function(){
      if(!this.$dialog || !this.$dialog.length) {
        return;
      }

      React.unmountComponentAtNode(this.$dialog[0]);
      this.$dialog.foundation('reveal', 'close');
    },
  },
  render : function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This gets rendered into the modal</h1>
        <a href="#" className="button" onClick={this.props.close}>Close</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```