# Global popup in React with Router and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I implemented a well working view layer in React JS where everything still operates on dummy data.

Now I need a modal popup that can be triggered from a lot of different components. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405669/react-modal-with-multiple-link-triggers) this could be nicely implemented with Redux, so I tried that.

After having to change my Router and reading countless docs I came up with

```
const Root = ({store}) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={...}/>

            <Popup visible={store.getState().taskEditPopup.open}>
                <...>
            </Popup>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)


ReactDOM.render(
    <Root store={store}/>,
    document.getElementById('react')
)
```

When the `Popup` is a child of `Provider`, it gives an error and as a child of Router it does not appear in the DOM.

So where to put this global modal? Is there a standard way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a top level component (i.e. `App`)?  It might be easier to nest it  there than in your routes.  And then you can `connect` it to `redux` just like any other component.

Comment: @adrice727 Well, `Root` is my current top level component, I will try another level. I never heard about `connect`, will look it up.

Comment: I added a small example in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think it's fairly common to use a top-level component (`App`) to nest things like headers/footers, global popups, etc.  You can then nest the rest of your routes inside `App`.

Routes example:

```
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <IndexRedirect to="login" />
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    </Route>
  </Router>);
```

Then within `App.js`:

```
import MyPopup from '../Popup/Popup';

const App = ({ children }) =>
  (<div className="App">
    <MyPopup />
    { children }
  </div>);

export default App;
```

And then you can [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) `MyPopup` and pass it `props` from redux.